# json undefined in jquery 2.0.2 ie10

Tags: jquery, json

We have a new asp.net web application, and we have just referrenced jquery 2.0.2 from google cdn, there is no other code. When we run it, we are getting Json undefined error.code is attached.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error (IE10 + visual studio 2012),
referencing Json2 library or setting doctype doesn't solve the problem.

I solved this by clearing all IE10 cache and browsing history.

Answer (score 0):

Well you load the `2.0.0` and not the `2.0.2`, but that's not the problem.
Your problem is that your document is not rendered in standart mode but in quirks mode and `JSON` - which is required by jquery - is only available in IE when the document is in standart mode.

See this article about the problem in IE9 (is should be the same as for IE 10):

[IE9 JSON Not Defined](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/fc41127c-0243-4d2e-8e7c-2b311f12e390/ie9-json-not-defined)

You use the doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Thats why IE is in <del>quirks</del> almost standart mode. To have you page in standart mode use the doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

A quote from the jQuery page:

> **Don’t use Quirks mode!** jQuery has never supported Quirks mode and we do not perform any testing in Quirks.

**EDIT**
I rechecked the used doctype. It should trigger the *almost standart* mode which should not be a problem, are you sure that you don't have any newline or other chars before the `doctype`? If changing the doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>` would not help, then give me a comment.

Comment: Thank you very mucht for the quick reply, I found IE 10 was running in compatibility mode and this was causing the problem. I am also going to check how the doctype is going to have an effect and will get back to you shortly

Comment: Here is a nice information if you want to do further reading [Activating Browser Modes with Doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/), but with `<!DOCTYPE html>` your are almost save.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue in IE9.  My page already had

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I added this to make it work.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```